# How to separate the print command on multiple lines

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a long string of text and break it into 2 lines when writing the code but when the code is running I want the line to appear as one line.

```
side1 = raw_input('Enter the length of the first side, of the triangle: ')
```

So i want to start a new line where the comma is in the text editor but when the code is running in python I want the question to appear as one line. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: did you try side1 = raw_input('Enter the length of the first side,\n of the triangle: ') ?

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear earlier I've edited it hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your new formulation yes it`s possible like that.

Simply put your new line in between the parentesis like that

```
side1 = raw_input('Enter the length of the first side,'
                  ' of the triangle: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `\n` (newline) character:

```
side1 = raw_input('Enter the length of the first side,\n of the triangle: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
side1 = raw_input('Enter the length of the first side, \n of the triangle: ')
```

`\n` for a new line, and `\t` for horizontal space (tabulation)